# A line graph for non-numeric data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a dataset with mostly non numeric forms. I would love to create a visualization for them but I am having an error message.

My data set looks like this

```
 |plant_name|Customer_name|Job site|Delivery.Date|DeliveryQuantity|
 |SN13|John|Sweden|01.01.2019|6|
 |SN14|Ruth|France|01.04.2018|4|
 |SN15|Jane|Serbia|01.01.2019|2|
 |SN11|Rome|Denmark|01.04.2018|10|
 |SN14|John|Sweden|03.04.2018|5|
 |SN15|John|Sweden|04.09.2019|7|
 |
```

I need to create a lineplot to show how many times John made a purchase using Delivery Date as my timeline (x-axis)

```
import  pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 5)

hr_data = pd.read_excel("D:\data\Days_Calculation.xlsx", parse_dates = True)

x = hr_data['DeliveryDate']
y = hr_data ['Customer_name']

sns.lineplot(x,y)

Error: No numeric types to aggregate
```

My expected result show be a line graph like this

John's marker will present on the timeline (Delivery Date) on "01.01.2019", "03.04.2018" and "04.09.2019"

Another instance 
To plot string vs float for example Total number of quantity (DeliveryQuantity) vs Customer Name .How can one approach this

how do one format the axes distance of a plot  (not label)

Comment: Have you checked `hr_data.head()` to make sure your data have loaded as expected? Also `'Deliv.Date'` or `Delivery Date`, `'Plant name'` or `plant name`, you code and your sample data conflict.

Comment: Can you create a mock of what you think this plot should look like? Also please include John more than once in your sample data. But as a hint, your `y` is cleary incorrect. Think about how you would filter the data to only show John? Next you need to create a count of purchases, take a look at the `.cumsum()` method applied to 'plant name' for this.

Comment: Don't think John features in x or y

Comment: I just edit the script.. i made a mistake.Have a look now

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you **have to aggregate something** when working with categorical data. Whether you will be counting names in a column or adding number of orders, or ranking some categories this is still numeric data.

```
plot_data = hr_data.pivot_table(index='DeliveryDate', columns='Customer_name', values='DeliveryQuantity', aggfunc='sum')

plt.xticks(LISTOFVALUESFORXRANGE)
plot_data.plot(legend=False)
```

Comment: I added a column in delivery quantity.. " the number of items purchase"

Comment: This looks good however if I have an instance to plot string vs float for example
Total number of quantity (DeliveryQuantity) vs Customer Name .How can one approach this?

Comment: @AKP update your question if you want to increase the scope

Comment: @bartek-malysz  

pd.pivot_table(index='DeliveryDate', columns='Customer_name', values='OrderQuantity', aggfunc='sum').plot()  

This expression produces a line graph not a pivot table and the line graph has a legend.  I looked at the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html  ) I didn't see any comment on legend. I want to drop the legend

Comment: This article will give you a grip on it. Not sure what you want, to have or jot to have pivot table? You can always convert it to dataframe or just keep for plot. Anyway if you want to get rid of the legend set legend=False in .plot() method and you're done. Check for other options in the article: “A Guide to Pandas and Matplotlib for Data Exploration” by Hugo Dolan https://link.medium.com/WkHWMzOSaX

Comment: @BartekMalysz thank you for your support. I saw an attribute for date on seaborn documentation.
 
fig.autofmtxdate()

It helped auto format the date label so they don't overlap.. Find more here  https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/relational.html

I will check out the link you provide. 

thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Why not make Delivery Date a timestamp object instead of a string?

```
hr_data["Delivery.Date"] = pd.to_datetime(hr_data["Delivery.Date"])
```

Now you got plot options.

Working with John.

```
john_data = hr_data[hr_data["Customer_name"]=="John"]
sns.countplot(john_data["Delivery.Date"])
```

Comment: this looks good however the x-axis is not tidy however can I format the width of the axes..